# Share spreedsheet created by service account

Tags: google-sheets-api

How can I share or change owner of a spreesheet, created via spreedsheet api authenticated by service account? Should I add and use Google Drive API for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have to use Google Drive API, but I cannot transfer owner to myself, because service account is located in another domain.